# How to set new list value based on condition in dataframe in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame like below.

```
+---+------------------------------------------+
|id |features                                  |
+---+------------------------------------------+
|1  |[6.629056, 0.26771536, 0.79063195,0.8923] |
|2  |[1.4850719, 0.66458416, -2.1034079]       |
|3  |[3.0975454, 1.571849, 1.9053307]          |
|4  |[2.526619, -0.33559006, -1.4565022]       |
|5  |[-0.9286196, -0.57326394, 4.481531]       |
|6  |[3.594114, 1.3512149, 1.6967168]          |
+---+------------------------------------------+
```

I want to set some of my features value based on my where condition like below. I.e. where `id=1`, `id=2` or `id=6`.

I want to set new  features value where `id=1`, I current features value is `[6.629056, 0.26771536, 0.79063195,0.8923]`, but I want to set `[0,0,0,0]`.

I want to set new  features value where `id=2`, I current features value is `[1.4850719, 0.66458416, -2.1034079]`, but I want to set `[0,0,0]`.

My final out put will be:

```
+------+-----------------------------------+
|id  | features                            |
+-----+---------------------------------- -+
|1  | [0, 0, 0, 0]                          |
|2  | [0,0,0]                              |
|3  | [3.0975454, 1.571849, 1.9053307]     |
|4  | [2.526619, -0.33559006, -1.4565022]  |
|5  | [-0.9286196, -0.57326394, 4.481531]  |
|6  | [0,0,0]                              |
+-----+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shaido's answer is fine if you have a limited set of `id` for which you know the length of the corresponding `feature` as well.

If that's not the case, it should be cleaner to use a UDF and the `id`s that you want to convert can be loaded in another `Seq` :

**In Scala**

```scala
val arr = Seq(1,2,6)

val fillArray = udf { (id: Int, array: WrappedArray[Double] ) =>
                        if (arr.contains(id) ) Seq.fill[Double](array.length)(0.0) 
                        else array 
                     }

df.withColumn("new_features" , fillArray($"id", $"features") ).show(false)
```

**In Python**

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *

arr = [1,2,6]

def fillArray(id, features):
    if(id in arr): return [0.0] * len(features)
    else : return features

fill_array_udf = f.udf(fillArray, ArrayType( DoubleType() ) )

 df.withColumn("new_features" , fill_array_udf( f.col("id"), f.col("features") ) ).show()
```

**Output**

```
+---+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|id |features                                  |new_features                       |
+---+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|1  |[6.629056, 0.26771536, 0.79063195, 0.8923]|[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]               |
|2  |[1.4850719, 0.66458416, -2.1034079]       |[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]                    |
|3  |[3.0975454, 1.571849, 1.9053307]          |[3.0975454, 1.571849, 1.9053307]   |
|4  |[2.526619, -0.33559006, -1.4565022]       |[2.526619, -0.33559006, -1.4565022]|
|5  |[-0.9286196, -0.57326394, 4.481531]       |[-0.9286196, -0.57326394, 4.481531]|
|6  |[3.594114, 1.3512149, 1.6967168]          |[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]                    |
+---+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Philantrovert,Thanks for quick reply,but I am expecting answer in python

Comment: Hi Philantrovert,Its working,but we need to import " from pyspark.sql.functions import col"

Comment: Thanks for informing. Corrected to `f.col` instead of `col`

Answer (score 1):

Use `when` and `otherwise` if you have a small set of ids to change:

```
df.withColumn("features", 
  when(df.id === 1, array(lit(0), lit(0), lit(0), lit(0)))
  .when(df.id === 2 | df.id === 6, array(lit(0), lit(0), lit(0)))
  .otherwise(df.features)))
```

It should be faster than an `UDF` but if there are many ids to change it quickly becomes a lot of code. In this case, use an `UDF` as in philantrovert's answer.

Comment: this is not really a scalable approach

Comment: @mtoto: Yes, for some reason I assumed there was only 3 different ids that should be changed. As I wrote in the answer, if there are more than a few then philantrovert's answer is preferable.